# How did SpaceX carry out livestreams initially?

Tags: spacex

The thing that probably captivated many of us here were the videos of the Falcon heavy boosters landing back perfectly.

How would one build a similar setup?

Comment: Put up a camera, point it at the landing pad(s), plug it into a computer, log into YouTube, click on "Start stream"? It's not quite clear what kind of answers you are looking for, or how this is related to Space Exploration. People have been filming events ever since film cameras were invented.

Comment: Please clarify, are you asking how they specifically operated the livestreams on a technical level like what cameras and radios SpaceX used or are you asking generally how one would livestream some arbitrary content?